# GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO PUBLIC - does not affects

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have tried to execute:

```
USE master
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION  TO PUBLIC
```

but all databases are not affected from this permission.

only when I am executing

```
USE SomeDB
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO PUBLIC
```

is affects, is there a limition for 'GRANT TO PUBLIC' ?

I am using

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL,'database')
```

and

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('ObjectName'))
```

to determine if user has right permission

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. What exactly is your problem? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to grant 'view definition' to all users in all databases. i thought that's 'view any definition to public'  make it. is incorrect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of how it's supposed to work.  You grant VIEW ANY DEFNINITION to PUBLIC then any login that can connect to a database gets VIEW DEFINITION at the database level.

```
use master
go
grant view any definition to public
drop database permtest 
go
drop login fred
go
create database permtest
go
use permtest
go
create login fred with password = 'as@#@315lkdfjlaskfj'
create user fred for login fred 
go
create proc foo as 
begin
  select 1 a
end
go

execute as login='fred'
 SELECT concat(entity_name, ': ', permission_name) 
 FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL,'database')

 SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('foo'))
revert
```

outputs

```
------------------
database: CONNECT
database: VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION
database: VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION
database: VIEW DEFINITION

(4 rows affected)


-------------
create proc foo as 
begin
  select 1 a
end

(1 row affected)
```

And if you change `grant` to `revoke` it outputs:

```
------------------
database: CONNECT
database: VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION
database: VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION

(3 rows affected)


--------------
NULL

(1 row affected)
```

But there has to be an active login for the server-level permission to apply.  It doesn't work with database-level principals like users without logins, contained database users, or when a database user is impersonated. And it doesn't grant logins access to databases they can't otherwise access.

Comment: David Browne :Your explanation of the difference between database-level \ server-level principals  Helped me. thanks.